# tcsetattr() blocking time with TCSADRAIN flag is weird

Tags: c++, c, linux, serial-port

I am coding with serial port in Linux.

And the requirement of the communication is `5ms inter-byte time`.

And It requires me to change parity mode(even and odd) for each byte before `write()` call, according to what the byte's value is.

So I code like below(i describe code simply)

```
void setWakeupMode(int fd, bool mode) {
    struct termios tio;

    bzero(&tio, sizeof(tio));
    tcgetattr(fd, &tio);


    if (mode == false) {
        tio.c_cflag &= ~PARODD;
    } else if (mode == true) {
        tio.c_cflag |= PARODD;
    }

    if(tcsetattr(fd, TCSADRAIN, &tio) < 0){
        perror("tcsetattr Error");
    }
}

int main(){
    unsigned char a[2] = {0x01, 0x0F};

    write(fd, a, 1);

    setWakeupMode(fd, true);

    write(fd, a+1, 1);

}
```

But the code doesn't satisfy inter-byte time resulting in almost 20ms.

So i tried print exact time between each system call like below.

```
   int main(){
        unsigned char a[2] = {0x01, 0x0F};

        printf("write1 start : %s", /*time*/);
        write(fd, a, 1);

        printf("write1 end  : %s", /*time*/); 
        setWakeupMode(fd, true);

        printf("write2 start : %s", /*time*/);
        write(fd, a+1, 1);

        printf("write2 end : %s, /*time*/);
    }
```

and This is the result

```
write1 start : 34.755201
write1 end   : 34.756046
write2 start : 34.756587  
write2 end   : 34.757349
```

This result suddenly satisfy the 5ms inter-byte time, resulting in `1ms inter-byte time`.

So i tried several ways.

And finally i recognize that only when i print something right before tcsetattr(), inter-byte time is satisfied.

for example, if i remove `printf("write1 end  : %s, /*time*/);` like below

```
   int main(){
        unsigned char a[2] = {0x01, 0x0F};

        printf("write1 start : %s", /*time*/);
        write(fd, a, 1);

        // printf("write1 end  : %s", /*time*/);  //remove this 
        setWakeupMode(fd, true);

        printf("write2 start : %s", /*time*/);
        write(fd, a+1, 1);

        printf("write2 end : %s", /*time*/);
    }
```

The result is surprisingly different, See the interval between `write1 start` and `write2 start`,
It is `18ms`.

```
write1 start : 40.210111
write2 start : 40.228332
write2 end   : 40.229187
```

If i use std::cout instead of printf, the result is same.

Why does this weird situration happen?

**-------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------**

Since i see some answers, some are misunderstanding my problem.

I am not worrying `printf()` overhead.

simply saying.

1. I want to call `write()`s with 1byte But the interval between `write()`s must be within 5ms
2. And Before calling `write()`, I have to change parity mode using `tcsetattr()`
3. But The interval result is `18ms`, being blocked at `tcsetattr()` almost time.
4. But If i call `printf()` or `std::cout` right before `tcsetattr()`, the interval reduce to `1~2ms`.

that is, somehow, calling printf before `tcsetattr()` make `tcsetattr()` return from blocking faster.

**--------------------------Update----------------------------**

I have progress on this problem.

I said that i had to put `printf()` or `std::cout` to make blocking time short on `tcsetattr()`.

But It was not printing something to affect to that problem.

It just needed some delay, that is, if i put `usleep(500)` before calling `tcsetattr()`, it also make an affect on inter-byte-time reducing by `1~2ms`, returning from `tcsetattr()` faster.

I assume, if i call `tcsetattr()` with `TCSADRAIN` flag, it wait until all data in serial buffer is transmitted, and change to the setting i want.

and it could make some delay.

but if i calling specifically delay, before i call `tcsetattr()`, the buffer state is already empty(because during the delay time, the data in serial buffer is transmitted), so that there is no blocking.

this is the scenario i assume, is it possible?

Comment: I can't see where you changed the interbyte time... Your measure doesn't indicate anything about the real transmission speed, your only measuring how much you spend in `write` system call. The device is free to have its own policy. How did you measure time ? real time ? user time ? elapsed time ? cpu time ? system time ?

Comment: See the interval between `write1 start` and `write2 start`, it take almost 18ms, and it is already over `5ms`. i want it to be within 5ms.

Comment: Try `fflush(fd)` or `fflush(stdout)` where that second `printf` statement is.  Does it have the same result as putting in the `printf`?

Comment: I put this part of code.
`FILE* fileStream= fdopen(fd, "r+")`

And put `fflush(fileStream)` or `fflush(stdout)` in the place of `printf("write1 end  : %s", /*time*/)`

But the result is same, 18ms

Comment: my suggestion: loose the printf statements.  printf is a very expensive function.  Rather use nanosleep() or something similar between the write() statements.

Comment: Did you made several tests? Are you sure that this is not due to process scheduling? In a standard system, you cannot ensure that your code is executed in a given delay if you don't use some kind of real-time process management... I also have a doubt that you need to change the parity mode in between each char!!! This is a very weird protocol.

Comment: Is `fd` in your code `stdout` or something else?

Comment: I tried also thread priority setting, but result is same, and fd is serial port.

the why i have to change parity mode, actually this protocol is using 9bit communication, and i want to use parity bit as 9th bit.

Comment: `tcsetaddr` with `TCSADRAIN` calls (in the kernel) `tty_wait_until_sent`, which as far as I can tell waits for the serial buffer to empty.  My best guess is that your `printf` statement somehow causes that to happen faster, but I don't see how.  If you want to use a 9th bit for parity, wouldn't you alter the character you are sending (adding a 1 or 0 in the 9th bit) rather than altering the parity mode?  I think this would be the normal way to do it.

Comment: I tried your (original) code on my PC that has a serial port, and cannot replicate your results.  I don't see a 18-20ms interval between characters, but only 5 to 6ms, with an occasional 4ms and a rare 8ms. The interval seems quantized; there is not a uniform variation across the range of 4 to 6 milliseconds.  Inserting a delay tends to make the interval longer, not shorter.  The interval does not seem related to baud rate.  These discrete intervals (that I measure) might depend on how the serial port driver delays for the drain operation.

Comment: **uart_wait_until_sent()** in `drivers/tty/serial/serial_core.c` explains why the interval between characters is quantized when a "drain" is involved: the serial port driver is polled for the TIOCSER_TEMP (transmitter empty) status using a delay with only millisecond resolution. So any baud rate faster than 9600 will poll at a rate slower than one character time, i.e. a poll rate no faster than once per 1 ms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this is the scenario i assume, is it possible?

You must be quite right. sawdust wrote:

> **uart_wait_until_sent()** in `drivers/tty/serial/serial_core.c` explains why the interval between characters is quantized when a "drain" is involved: the serial port driver is polled for the TIOCSER_TEMP (transmitter empty) status using a delay with only millisecond resolution.

That's almost right, except that the polling cycle resolution is not milliseconds, but jiffies:

```
         while (!port->ops->tx_empty(port)) {
                 msleep_interruptible(jiffies_to_msecs(char_time));
                 …
```

So if HZ is 100 and `char_time` is 1 (the minimum), the status is checked every 10 ms. As you wrote:

> but if i calling specifically delay, before i call `tcsetattr()`, the
>   buffer state is already empty(because during the delay time, the data
>   in serial buffer is transmitted), so that there is no blocking.

In other words, if you delay the process long enough that by the time it gets to the transmitter empty test `!port->ops->tx_empty(port)` the transmitter is already empty, no sleep occurs; otherwise it sleeps for at least 1 jiffy.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try sprintf / snprintf instead printf??
Because about snprintf, you may Speed the time if
you shortened the string-Byte?